# I have a Macbook Air, early 2014. How do i get 3840x2160 resolution output?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am getting only 1080p on my 4K TV, via thunderbolt to HDMI adapter. I want to know how to get more resolution output.

Answer (score 2):

That Macbook Air is only capable of 2560 x 1600 maximum resolution, according to [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i7-1.7-13-early-2014-specs.html)

> Although Apple only reports that this model can support a single external display up to 2560x1600, Intel reports that this model can simultaneously support two external displays up to 2560x1600 "daisy chained" via Thunderbolt.

There's a possibility you are limited to 1080p by the HDMI cable. make sure it's HDMI 1.4 capable.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU (Graphics Processing Unit) on a 2014 Air doesn't support 4K resolutions over HDMI, you'd need a newer model for this (early 2015).

Source: [Using 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac (apple.com)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856)

Answer (score 0):

Do not take NO for answer.  I have an early 2014 MacBook Air.  Buy Mini DisplayPort to HDMI VGA DVI Adapter, FOINNEX Thunderbolt 2/Mini Dp Converter. It is $13.59 on Amazon. I bought it and connected to a Samsung 28" 4K monitor. It works!

Comment: Who said "No" that he should take as an answer?